# Is it bad to use special symbols in URL?

Tags: url, url-encoding

Context: ASP.NET MVC 2.0

I want to support URL of following format:

`wowreforge.com?Exp=220,Hit<461,Mastery>Haste>Crit`

It works in both FF and IE. They both escape symbols correctly when entered.

**My question:** are there any reasons not to use the URL-form above?

*Background*
I want the URL to be usable as a general formula that you can paste in a thread discussion, or instant message. Something like:

> I think that for combat rogue **wowreforge.com?Exp=220,Hit<461,Mastery>Haste>Crit** is the best reforging strategy.

Any alternative implementation ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always run such values through your web framework's URL Encode function. Such functions will encode values which need to be encoded, and not encode those which do not.

This is better than trying to guess which characters are OK in a query string and which are not.

Also note that you should apply this encoding on the values of each query string parameter - not on the *entire* query string itself. (otherwise you would end up improperly encoding the ampersand that splits parameters, for example)

Comment: That's the point. I want URL to be readable verbatim, but it seems like browsers do the encoding when you try to use the link. I also want to allow users to create such URL manually.

Comment: You can not and should not rely on such behavior from browsers. But also read Gumbo's answer: he notes how some browsers actually take the encoded link, and display in the browser the characters that those codes create. This could also enable a user to manually edit the URL in the address bar. **But** when you are building those links in your web site as anchor tags, you *must* encode them properly - regardless of what the browser will do to them.

Answer (score 1):

`<` and `>` are not allowed in a URL and *must* be encoded with the percent-encoding.

But besides that there is a difference between how browser display URLs and how they are actually encoded. For example, modern browsers display sequences of percent-encoded words that represent characters in UTF-8 as the characters they represent rather than the encoded words. So a URL like `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F` is often displayed as `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ß` although it is actually encoded as `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F`.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 1738 says this is a bad idea:

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL."

Try encoding all of the special characters using the ASCII control codes.  This is the safe way to send special characters via a URL.